# What is "Java error. Invalid format"?

Tags: java-me, mobile-phones

I have made my own application in J2me to my mobile phone. The previous versions of this application works perfectly. But now (after a few changes in source code), when I copy this appplication to my mobile phone (Smasung gt-s7550) I get: `Java error. Invalid format` and the application doesn't start. 
Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 0):

invalid format can mean all kinds of different things. Without seeing any code, my guess would be a missing semi-colon or something to that effect.

Comment: But in emulator (netbeans) it work fine without any warnings or errors (missing semi-colon would cause an error)